# Change the Space Between Paragraphs Without Messing up Other Parts of the Document

Tags: spacing, paragraphs, parskip

For quite some time I was trying to adjust the space between paragraphs by tweaking `parskip` but after asking two question in here I saw that messing around with it is not a good idea. That is because `parskip` is a variable that is present in a lot of places within a document (for example in the space between section and subsection titles and in lists). So with every answer in my questions I got even more questions!

This seems to me something that must be easily achieved because it is pretty straighforward and also something that people tweak a lot. Nevertheless I haven't managed to find a good way to do it without changing other aspects of the document.

So all in all:

1. If someone wants to "safely" change only the space between the paragraphs without mess up other places in the document what is the best way to succeed it?
2. Why is it such a big deal to simply put extra space between paragraphs? I simply can't understand why there is so much fuss about it!

Comment: I think you have to restrict your question to the first part (the No 1.) The second is something out of the purposes of the forum... (too broad etc).

Comment: @koleygr You may be right but I think it is relevant to the question because if `parskip` is so much of a trouble we may very well include as to why that is. Also having seen a lot of answers being literally pages long I don't think that an answer to this question will be an issue, even if it is extensive. :)

Comment: I just wanted to say that you can rephrase this specific question not to seem like too broad. For example, you could ask for a list of changes in the document after changing the parskip (real specific and get your answer too without risk of comments like mine :P). Also this would help me to give you an answer (because I could include to the environments that are affected a negative `\vspace` or `\vskip` after redefining them)

Comment: @koleygr Oh I see. The thing is that I have searched extensively for such questions to no avail so generally from what I saw is that it is far better to not change the `parskip`. The reason that this question is phrased like that is because I don't want to touch `parskip`! :P Except of course if there is a way to not mess up the rest of the document...

Comment: I am not sure what answer this question can have other than the answers you already know. If you are designing a document layout which has visible space between paragraphs, you would start by setting `\parskip` and then specify space around headings, lists, math displays etc taking account of the pararagraph space already added.  If on the other hand you just want to alter an existing layout that was not designed with an option for non-zero paragraph space, then you need to adjust whatever lengths need adjusting, that depends on the class, how many environments it defined.

Comment: your question would be clearer if you made a small example document using a standard class and the parskip package, or alternatively a class designed for non-zero parskip such as one of the koma or ntg classes  and then asked about a specific document element that had a space that you wanted to change.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't have something specific in my mind that is why I didn't include a MWE. I was searching whether there was a more general solution as to how someone can have specific space between the paragraphs without messing up other spaces in the document. I didn't think it would be this complex a question. I will probably delete it. Thank you for your time though.

Comment: The question in that form is not answerable. You need to change `\parskip` the question (which only you can answer) is "what do you consider to be a paragraph?"  list items are paragraphs so by default they will be affected, if you want them to not have extra space you need to reset their definition. Section headings come between paragraphs, so changing parskip adds space (that would be there if the heading were not present) that may or may not make the space around the heading look too much so you may need to adjust spacing around section headings to add less space, and so it goes on.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right. I hadn't thought of paragraphs that way. Thank you.

Comment: I suppose if you found that comment useful I could make an answer along those lines?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes it is certainly useful as it shows that this is a far more complex issue than first though. If you want I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You (or a class that you choose) need to change `\parskip`. The question (which only you can answer) is "what do you consider to be a paragraph?"

If you are designing a document layout which has visible space between paragraphs, you would start by setting `\parskip` and then specify space around headings, lists, math displays etc taking account of the paragraph space already added. If on the other hand you just want to alter an existing layout that was not designed with an option for non-zero paragraph space, then you need to adjust whatever lengths need adjusting, that depends on the class, how many environments it defined.  the `parskip` package tries to make a reasonable guess at doing this for the standard classes such as `article` although as it notes in its documentation this is not really as good as designing a class with this option from the start.

To see why it is not such a simple question, consider some examples.

list items are paragraphs so by default they will be affected, if you want them to not have extra space you need to reset their definition to add less space.

Section headings come between paragraphs, so changing parskip adds space (that would be there if the heading were not present) that may or may not make the space around the heading look too much so you may need to adjust spacing around section headings to add less space, and so it goes on.

Note for section headings you probably want to *choose* some length based on some under specified notion of what looks good. If you have a large `\parskip` and that is added to the space already added around display headings then they may look too spaced out, but conversely if you were to automatically suppress all the `\parskip` space near a section heading you could find that section headings are more closely spaced than just a normal paragraph break, which would be odd, so really the entire document design as implemented in the class needs to be reconsidered if paragraph spacing is changed.

That said, for most documents most of the time, choosing a common class where this has been considered in advance (Koma classes and memoir have options for this or the NTG `artikel3` class is a variant of article with non zero parskip) or using `parskip` package to adjust the settings in the standard classes works in a reasonable way.